# WriteConsoleOutputCharacter doesn't print the symbol

Tags: c++, winapi

It basically just prints a question mark, and I can't see what I did wrong.

```
   COORD coord;
coord.Y = 10;
coord.X = 50;
HANDLE Handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
wchar_t* caster = new wchar_t['x'];
DWORD saver;
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Handle, caster, 1, coord, &saver);
```

Comment: `new wchar_t['x'];` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: If anyone needs it for whatever purpose 
wchar_t chr = 'x';
wchar_t* caster = &chr;

Comment: You don't even need the (temporary) `caster` variable, just use `&chr` directly in the call to `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`. Or perhaps even just `L"x"`.

Comment: @Some Just out of curiosity: Isn't the `L` needed for the character literal also?

Comment: @Lizi34 You can self answer your question, if you already found a solution.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes that's true.

Comment: @Lizi34 ^^^^ So, you should consider this with your solution. Also to solve the "riddle" `new wchar_t['x']` allocates an array of 120 `wchar_t`'s.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yep, thanks, you're awesome. I guess the 120 comes from converting the char 'x' to int?

Comment: @Lizi34 yes, 120 is the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the character `'x'`.

Comment: @Lizi34 Does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> new wchar_t['x'];

This creates a wide char array and its length is the integer value of the character `x`. It seems not what you want.

If you want to print the character `x` you can achieve it like this:

```
wchar_t* caster = new wchar_t[1] {'x'};
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Handle, caster, 1, coord, &saver);
```

or

```
WCHAR caster = 'x';
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(Handle, &caster, 1, coord, &saver);
```